# How to get userlibs in the Rexx-interface to SDSF

Tags: zos, rexx, sdsf

The rexx interface to SDSF works fine to get information about spoolfiles. I am trying to list the use of userlibs for output-files. And do a "ISFEXEC O" followed by (in a loop)

ISFACT O TOKEN(..) PARM(NP ?) (PREFIX JDS_ DELAYED DELAYED2

In an inner loop I can then run through each JDX_xxxx. variable. Sofar so good. But how do I get information on userlib no. 2,3,4 ...? JDS_ODUSRLIB. gives me the first userlib. But how do I get hold of the other 7 userlibs?

I have tried for find any example bit with no luck and the documentation is not very clear on this subject.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried the JDS_ODUSRLIB. stem? Something like

```
  do jx=1 to JDS_DDNAME.0   /* loop for all rows returned */
    say "UsrLib for " JDS_DDNAME.jx " is " JDS_ODUSRLIB.jx                          
  end
```

Comment: Hi. Thanks for the reply. Yes, I use that. The problem is that per DDNAME there can be up to 8 userlibs. The JDS_ODUSRLIB only contains the first one. I do not know how to get hold of the other 7. The manual is not very clear on this - in my humble opinion.

Comment: Hi, I'm wondering if you can see the other 7 on your SDSF panels. If you don't see it there, I would assume, that the information isn't available. Maybe you can find the information using PARM(NP Q) instead of NP ?

Comment: If you are missing column UserLib on OD panel (requested with NP Q), you should use the ALTERNATE parm on ISFEXEC.

Comment: Yes, I can see all 8 userlibs on the SDSF panels (using the ALTERNATE form). But I cannot figure out how to get them into REXX. The ODUSRLIB stem variable is only one value per job dataset. It cannot contain 8 different values per job dataset.

Comment: Found that unfortunately NP Q is not allowed (see https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSLTBW_2.3.0/com.ibm.zos.v2r3.isfa600/rxacref.htm#rxacref__xtabacs). Looks like where is no chance to get it over SDSF REXX API.

Comment: RGEN Never tried, but maybe interesting for you: https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSLTBW_2.3.0/com.ibm.zos.v2r3.isfa600/rexgen.htm#rexgen

Comment: Yes it reaaly seems like there is no way of getting more than the first userlib from SDSF to the REXX-code. ... And I have tried RGEN. It does not provide any sample code for accessing fields on the Output Descriptor panels. So I guess it ends here with the usual: It is not a bug, it's a feature. I hope someone from IBM is also listening to this thread and maybe prepare a PTF to implement the function.